# Prevent users from navigating between tabpages

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I created a tabControl and TABpages and I would like to prevent users from navigating between them. I would also like the menu to be visible and the user can't access a tabpage when selecting it from tabcontrol.

I tried to use the remove and Add but in this case the menu disappears and only the tab that I am on appears. I tried to set the enabled property to false and in this case the user can access the tab page but nothing appears which I don't want to happen.

I tried the e.cancel with tabcontrol_selecting event and it worked and the other tabs were locked, but when I tried to navigate between tabpages using the code it did not work. In fact, on the first page, there is a login interface, when the arguments are correct it should take me to the second tabpage, and this did not happen.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

This is the code of going from the login tab to the second tab:

```
Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
        If Usersel.SelectedIndex = 0 And Password.Text = "0000" Then
            TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1
        End If
```

This is the selecting event

```
Private Sub TabControl_Selecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl.Selecting, TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged

        e.Cancel = False

            Dim messageBoxVB As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "TabPage", e.TabPage)
            messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
            messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "TabPageIndex", e.TabPageIndex)
            messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
            messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Action", e.Action)
            messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
            messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Cancel", e.Cancel)
            messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxVB.ToString(), "Selecting Event")



    End Sub
```

This is the menu and how I would like it to be all the time:

[image: menu]

Comment: Use a class variable to store the valid index say: `curIndex`. In the `Enter_Click` set the `curIndex = 1 : TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1`. In the `TabControl_Selecting` event set `e.Cancel = True` If `curIndex <> e.TabPageIndex`.

Comment: When I do that I get this error System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs'.'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code:

```
Private isCanceled As Boolean = True
Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 And Password.Text = "0000" Then
        isCanceled = False
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    If e.TabPage.Equals(TabPage2) Then
        e.Cancel = isCanceled
    End If
End Sub
```

Only TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 and Password.Text = "0000", you can navigate to TabPage2.